# What is happening in this recursion?

Tags: python, recursion

I wrote this code to understand a certain algorithm. But I still don't get how the recursion is working here. Can anybody please explain it to me. I understand the output till line 5 where it first prints "It got here", but after that it becomes a little confusing for me.
The code:

```
def empty(n):
    print("recur ",n)
    if(n==1):
        print("end")
        return(0)
    empty(n-1)
    print("It got here")
    empty(n-1)
```

when I call this function

```
empty(3)
```

This is the output I get

```
recur  3  
recur  2  
recur  1  
end  
It got here  
recur  1  
end  
It got here  
recur  2  
recur  1  
end  
It got here  
recur  1  
end
```

Comment: create a diagrammatic stack to understand. After you get the first "It got here", the flow will proceed with value of `n = 2` into the last call of `empty(n-1)` and when that finishes, the flow will proceed with `n=3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

each function call does the following things:

- print the argument as an indicator for the current recursion depth
- call the function recursively
- print "It got there"
- call the function recursively again (same output as two steps above)

If you separate these output blocks with blank lines, it looks like this:

```
recur 3

recur 2
recur 1
end
It got there
recur 1
end

It got there

recur 2
recur 1
end
It got there
recur 1
end
```

the following block appeared 2 times:

```
recur 2
recur 1
end
It got there
recur 1
end
```

It is build in the same way:

```
recur 2

recur 1
end

It got there

recur 1
end
```

When you visualize the recursion depth with indentation, your output could look like this:

```
recur 3
    recur 2
        recur 1
        end
    It got there
        recur 1
        end
It got there
    recur 2
        recur 1
        end
    It got there
        recur 1
        end
```